# Best way to add comment field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Currently I am creating a site that I would like users to be able to comment in.  I am just having a hard time wrapping my head around how to model the models so to speak.  The way I have it, I believe that the comments aren't connecting themselves to the main article, I believe they just get added and sunk into the abyss.  What's the best way to connect the models?  Should I just not have a separate model for the comments?  This is more of a hypothetical question than a how to code question.  Currently this is the way I have it.

```
    class Comments(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    comment = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=5000)
    date = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, primary_key=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    usedfor = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    url=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    article_programming_language = models.ForeignKey(ProgrammingLanguage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    article_framework = models.ForeignKey(Framework, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="article_framework", blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.IntegerField( max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    article_comments = models.ForeignKey(Comments, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Probably easier to have a `ForeignKey` inside **Comments** pointing to **Article**. This way will be easier to keep them connected and you can still list all comments from an article really easy.

Comment: I assume that an Article can have zero or more Comments.  If so Bruno is right you want a `article = ForeignKey(Article, ...)` field inside Comments. And you'll want to get rid of the `article_comments` in the Article model.

Comment: Foreign keys work the other way. Currently your comment is the parent and article is the child, i.e. 1 comment <-> many articles.

Comment: Use `ManyToManyField` instead of `ForeignKey` to `Comments` in your `Article` model.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you have got all the things you need in your class.Here's some opinions.

1. Comments should be a separate model.
2. Each comment should be addressed to a specific user (or an anonymous user).A user could have many comments, but a comment should only be created by one user.Adding a ForeignKey inside comments as [Bruno Monteiro] advised could help.
3. Each comment should be addressed to a specific article.This could also be an One-To-Many Relationship(An article could have many comments,but a comment only belongs to a specific article).

'Best design' is too huge to answer.The design that meets your need is the best.So when you want to find a 'best design', just ask yourself what functions it will provide, how the comments should work,etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion,

1. Create a comment model,
2. Add user model with a f.k. `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)` # You can add null and blank as per your requirement
3. Add article model with a f.k., `article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlecomment')`
4. Add date with auto_now_add = True

Here users can add any number of comments they want.